# centOS server openoffice headless

Tags: openoffice.org, centos

I am trying to start openOffice as a service on CentOS(non-graphical) server.

```
soffice -headless -nologo -nofirststartwizard -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp" & > /dev/null 2>&1
```

How ever I am getting below error

```
 Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)

[1]+  Done                    soffice -headless -nologo -nofirststartwizard -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp"
```

This command works just fine in Ubuntu.
Can you please suggest how can I start OpenOffice as a service on CentOS server?

Comment: Related: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=11890

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works for me on CentOS 5:

1. yum install openoffice.org-headless
2. soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard &

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the problem, but it might be that your program cannot contact the X11 server because it was launched from the CLI. Try this:

```
xhost +
```

That enables the use of Xorg for apps launched from the CLI.
I am not sure if it has to be ran as root or not (IIRC, you must *NOT* run it as root).

Comment: When I executed the command "xhost +", I got error message xhost:  'unable to open display ""'. Just an FYI this is a non graphical centOS server. Any reason why it would run fine in Ubuntu and not in centOS.